# Python3 - Change visibility of PSD layers programmatically

Tags: python-3.x

Is possible to programmatically change PSD layer visibility in a PSD, without use Photoshop?

I did check various implementation of PSD libraries for Python, but the best they do is to return the visibility value (like `psd_tools`); but the visible property is read only, so I can't change it.

I wish there was a way to be able to extract and manipulate groups and layers in PSD files, directly from Python; but the best I can do is to use psd_tools to retrieve layers and stack them together; after export them as PNG; although this is not ideal

Answer (score 3):

If anybody is wondering... You can actually turn visibility on layers with `psd-tools`. And if you save that PSD with psd-tools, it will show properly when opened with Photoshop.
However, if you save it to PNG, it won't show your changes, unless you set param `force` to `True` when calling `.compose()` function. It took me some time to realize that.

Example:

```
from psd_tools import PSDImage

psd = PSDImage.open( filename )
psd[0].visible = False             # Set first layer to invisible
image = psd.compose( force=True )  # Very important to set force param!
image.save( "output.png" )
```