# Save PSD to JPG without invisible layers

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, psd

I would like to export a PSD file for which we put some group layers as invisible to JPG.

Currently, I tried to put the concerned group layers as invisible (by looping through the PSD layers and put the concerned group as invisible like `group.visible = False`) and then save that PSD.

The saved new PSD does have the concerned group layers invisible.

Later, the new PSD is converted to JPG.
However, the JPG output shows also the invisible layers.

The python code used for passing from the new saved PSD to JPG is like the same for saving (we used psd_tools).

```
from psd_tools import PSDImage 

image= PSDImage.open(PSDFilePath)
image.save(outputPath, "JPEG")
```

I have also tried with the command line "convert" on linux but it has also showed the invisible layers after conversion.

So, my question is to know whether there's a way to either remove invisible layers before saving to JPG within the same script without calling a script inside PhotoShop (which requires to open instances of PhotoShop) or export it to JPG without removing with a python code or maybe a command line.

---

I have found the last days something that does the trick from [this StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270390/python3-change-visibility-of-psd-layers-programmatically) by adding **composite(force=True)**

```py
from psd_tools import PSDImage 

image= PSDImage.open(PSDFilePath)
image.composite(force=True).save(outputPath) #outputPath is expected to be a JPG file
```

This is pretty good for light files. However, when the PSD's size is very large like 1GB, it takes too much time.
As I would like to execute this operation on a daily basis on about > 1000 files, this would take days to be done.

So, I am always looking for another solution.

Here's a sample to a lighter file, unfortunately, I could not put the real one for professional reasons.
https://file.io/yxdDxlzMeMsA

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared a representative sample PSD file, preferably showing a screen-grab of the Layers palette so invisible layers can be identified. You'd likely need to use Dropbox or Google Drive. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell for your feedback. I have put one as a sample and would like to save that to jpg by putting the layer called **InvisibleLayer** invisible in the JPG output.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea of what can be done with maybe other than psd-tools ?